# Ncurses: how to refresh a menu without losing current position?

Tags: c, ruby, menu, ncurses, user-interaction

How can I reload the data in a menu without losing the current position?

For example, when a user "selects" an item, and an action is performed that changes the data. (Either updating the item, removing it, or adding a new item to the menu.) I'd like to reload the menu but still keep the cursor on the item that was just selected. What's the best way to do this?

---

For reference, this question seemed very close, but I don't think it covers the add/remove issue: [How to replace a string menu item in ncurses & C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252340/how-to-replace-a-string-menu-item-in-ncurses-c)

This question also seemed similar, but was too specific for me: [Ncurses menu - remembering selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016512/ncurses-menu-remembering-selection)

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448130/menu-dividers-in-ncurses/34454987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rebuild a menu, your program will have to keep track of what was the "current" item before, and find that before resuming its reads via `getch`.  The [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) function refreshes the screen, and the position which your program has set for the `getch` becomes the apparent cursor position.

Normally you would use `item_index` to ask the menu library which is the current item, and [`set_current_item`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/mitem_current.3x.html) to tell the menu-library which item the cursor would be on, but it's possible to do your calls to `getch` "anywhere" on the screen.  Likewise, if you rebuild a menu, that index information may be stale.

Without some specific sample program, there's only general advice which can be offered.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to keep the question generic for now, so this answer seems spot-on for me.